# Setting CSS Expression using $.css() in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set a css expression for an attribute for an element as follows.

```
var scrollTopExpr = '$(document).scrollTop()';
var expr = "expression(eval(" + scrollTopExpr + "))";
$(this).css("top", expr);
```

But i'm getting "Invalid Argument" as an error. Any ideas?

Comment: What browser is this in? CSS expressions are only supported by IE, and in IE8 only when in comptability mode, because they are considered deprecated by Microsoft.

Comment: I'm trying to do position fixed and i'm trying to support IE6+ FF 2.0+. But IE7 and IE8 is not supporting postion:fixed without a doctype. I'm doing an addon product for a CMS system where i cant give my own doctype. How can i do it then?

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoters spend couple of minutes telling the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions were deprecated and removed in IE8 (unless you're in compatibility mode).  They're also performance hogs and you should stay away from them if you can, using JavaScript instead.

You don't need to use *eval()* inside *expression()*, and this is what's causing your error.  *eval()* expects a string, but you're passing the result of a variable to it, which is a *Number*.  Take out *eval()*:

```
"expression(" + scrollTopExpr + ")";
```

*expression()* already evaluates the expression you pass to it, so *eval()* is entirely unnecessary.